# Call Python function in Bottle without redirecting

Tags: python, html, bottle

I'm making really simple web app to simplify capturing tcpdump on our server for a user (I'm mostly network engineer, not web developer, so this task is a real pain for me)

I've chosen Bottle for this.
App has text box, where user can input IP, and Start and Stop buttons

part of 'buttons.tpl' template:

```
<button name="start" type="submit" form="data" formaction="/start" formmethod="post">Start</button>
```

Python script:

```
@route('/')
def mainform():
        output = template('buttons')
        return output
@route('/start', method='POST')
def startaction():
        ip = request.forms.get('ip')
        os.system("tcpdump start")
        return "Started tcpdump"
```

My question is: how I can avoid redirect to /start?

I just need to let user to stay on this main page after pressing Start(and starting tcpdump on server), but even if I remove 'return' it still redirects user to /start

Comment: You could use an approach with AJAX. Take a look [here](http://enricorossi.org/blog/2012/python_bottle_and_ajax/)

Comment: You can use AJAX or return `template('buttons')` on the `startaction()` method